# How can I copy an IDENTITY field?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I’d like to update some parameters for a table, such as the dist and sort key. In order to do so, I’ve renamed the old version of the table, and recreated the table with the new parameters (these can not be changed once a table has been created).

I need to preserve the id field from the old table, which is an IDENTITY field. If I try the following query however, I get an error:

```
insert into edw.my_table_new select * from edw.my_table_old;
ERROR: cannot set an identity column to a value [SQL State=0A000]
```

How can I keep the same id from the old table?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't *INSERT* data setting the *IDENTITY* columns, but you can load data from S3 using **[COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html)** command.

First you will need to create a dump of source table with [UNLOAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html).

Then simply use **[COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html)** with **[EXPLICIT_IDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-explicit-ids)** parameter as described in [Loading default column values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading_default_values.html):

> If an IDENTITY column is included in the column list, the EXPLICIT_IDS
>   option must also be specified in the COPY command, or the COPY command
>   will fail. Similarly, if an IDENTITY column is omitted from the column
>   list, and the EXPLICIT_IDS option is specified, the COPY operation
>   will fail.

Comment: Use [ALTER TABLE APPEND](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html#r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND_usage), see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40211868/1265306), it is much faster and more simple.

Comment: 2naviram: your approach didn't work for me with IDENTITY column :/ (With 'Columns don't match' error, even if table definitions are the same. Created with 'CREATE TABLE test (LIKE source INCLUDING DEFAULTS);')

Answer (score 7):

You can explicitly specify the columns, and ignore the identity column:

`insert into existing_table (col1, col2) select col1, col2 from another_table;`

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I needed in case of RedShift

Answer (score 1):

Use [ALTER TABLE APPEND](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html) twice, first time with IGNOREEXTRA and the second time with FILLTARGET.

> If the target table contains columns that don't exist in the source
>   table, include FILLTARGET. The command fills the extra columns in the
>   source table with either the default column value or IDENTITY value,
>   if one was defined, or NULL.

It moves the columns from one table to another, extremely quickly; took me 4s for 1GB table in dc1.large node.

> Appends rows to a target table by moving data from an existing source
>   table.
>   ...
>   ALTER TABLE APPEND is usually much faster than a similar CREATE TABLE
>   AS or INSERT INTO operation because data is moved, not duplicated.

Faster and simpler than UNLOAD + COPY with EXPLICIT_IDS.

Comment: This only works if the source and target table attributes match.  And that includes DistKey and SortKey.  Since the original poster mentions that they specifically want to change the DistKey and SortKey, this method will not work for their scenario.

Comment: It also doesn't copy the old table's identity column's values into the new table's identity column. Instead, it allows the new table to generate new identity values, which can (and likely will) be different from the old identity values.  *(APPEND is certainly useful, and fast, but completely useless as an answer to this question's use-case.)*  `You can't append an identity column. If both tables include an identity column, the command fails. If only one table has an identity column, include the FILLTARGET or IGNOREXTRA parameter. For more information, see ALTER TABLE APPEND Usage Notes.`