# if I load data from S3 to Redshift using the COPY command, will it follow my dist style and keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Background: In Redshift, I want to add a distribution key to an existing table that has an identity column, just like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822569/how-can-i-copy-an-identity-field).

I am confused by the answer on that question -- I thought that to have my table data stored according to a certain dist key, I have to INSERT the data, I can't just COPY or APPEND from an undistributed table. Is this different when COPYing from S3?

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting methods on the Questions you linked!

**You cannot add a Distribution Key to an existing table.** You would need to create a new table, then copy the data across. This can be done via `INSERT INTO new-table SELECT * FROM old-table`.

When data is loaded into an Amazon Redshift table, it *ALWAYS* honors the Distribution Key because the `DISTKEY` determines which slice stores the data. Whether you use `COPY` (which is preferred) or an `INSERT`, data will always be distributed according to the `DISTKEY`.

The `SORTKEY` will also be used when data is loaded via `COPY`, but existing data will not be re-sorted. For example, if you have a column of data already loaded in alphabetical order, then newly-loaded rows will be added to the *end* of the existing data. This new data will be sorted, but the column as a *whole* will not be sorted. Use a `VACUUM` command to re-sort the whole table.

Whenever possible, you should use the `COPY` command to load data into a Redshift table. This allows Redshift to load the data in parallel using all nodes. Try to minimize the amount of data loaded via `INSERT` — preferably load multiple rows using this method. Try to avoid `INSERT` single rows, which is very inefficient in Redshift compared to bulk loading.